# Can I change the PayPal item_number for existing recurrent payments from my users?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I added a Donate button to my website, with multiple options (like $2/mo, $3/mo etc) Because of my mistake, I only created one subscription profile on my database, therefore all the donation get the same `item_number` regardless of the price.

This is a problem because the PayPal implementation I use, *django_paypal* coupled with *django-subscriptions*, checks the incoming amount when it receives an IPN, and whether it matches the amount specified in a subscription.

So the subscription that I created, was called "Donor", and had a specified amount of $2. When people subscribe with a recurrent donation different from $2, the subscription expiry date isn't updated by *django-subscriptions* because the payment results incorrect, or so *django_paypal* thinks.

Now I've added multiple subscriptions (Donor $2, Donor $3, etc) and I would like to modify the IPNs of my subscribers manually, so that the IPN that I receive has the correct |item_number|.

Is it possible to do this perhaps in some administrative console at PayPal?